# Determinant equation.

Tags: linear-algebra

let
A = [[x,-1],
    [3,(1-x)]]
and 
B = [[1,0,-3],
     [2,x,-6],
     [1,3,(x-5)]]

solve for x;

det(A) = det(B)

on expanding both the determinants and equating them, i obtain;

$-2x^2+3x+3 = 0$

completeing the square

$2[x^2-\frac{3x}{2}] -3 = 0$

$2[(x-\frac{3}{4})^2 - \frac{9}{16}] -3 = 0$

$2(x-\frac{3}{4})^2 - \frac{18}{16} -3 = 0$

$(x-\frac{3}{4}) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{33}{16}}$

$x = \frac{3}{4} \pm \sqrt{\frac{33}{16}}$

The answer in the back of the book is not this, could someone shed some light please.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ejll6pi7nhb

Comment: Books are wrong sometimes.

Comment: generally the solutions of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ are given by $x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ax}}{2a}$. But your solution is also correct.

Comment: What book is it ?

Comment: Anton Rorres Elementary linear algebra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have properly solved this exercise. Actually you can simplify the result:
$$x = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{33}}{4}$$

Comment: ahh i have been pulling my hair out all day haha. damn books